# tcp::acceptor object causing boost::asio::io_service::run to exit immediately in .so file

Tags: c++, boost, server, boost-asio

I have used boost async io for my application server. I have been following [boost chat tutorial](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/chat/). when I make a standalone server executable all asynchronous( async_read, async_write, post) operation are getting executed on call to boost::asio::io_service::run, but when i tried to use the same class inside my shared object(.so) file, boost::asio::io_service::run call returns immediately. Problem is occurring after creation of tcp::acceptor object. I commented tcp::acceptor object creation and tried post asyn operation in my so code, it got executed correctly on call to boost::asio::io_service::run.

I am total beginner to boost asio, kindly help me understand why boost::asio::io_service::run call returns immediately when used in so code

Edit:
I am using a third party api and loading my shared object file dynamically. I created mcve code for loading my so dynamically and calling my so functions but boost::asio::io_service::run function is running fine on my mcve code. What other steps can i take to debug problem in io_service

Comment: Unless this is a common problem specific to Boost.asio, you probably need to reduce your code to an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for anyone to be able to help. Without seeing code it's generally hard to tell what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found issue, it was caused due to different gcc version used for api executable and so file